# Auto close on multiple sliding panels using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I Have a section of sliding panels that works quite nicely but my problem is that once you open one then click on a second or third panel the previous panel's do not close and stay open which looks very messy, I have a link to my code in [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pcD8D/7/). So I'm wondering if I can add some code that can auto close previously opened panels when a new one is clicked on?

current jQuery code looks like:

```
    $("#team_section .team_member_photo").next().hide().append('<input type="button" value="close" />');

    $("#team_section .team_member_photo").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $("input").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().slideUp();
    });
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="team_wrapper">
  <div id="team_section" class="clearfix">

            <div class="team_member_photo">photo 0</div>
            <div class="team_member_profile_text"><p>text</p></div>

            <div class="team_member_photo">photo 1</div>
            <div class="team_member_profile_text"><p>text</p></div>

            <div class="team_member_photo">photo 2</div>
            <div class="team_member_profile_text"><p>text</p></div>

            <div class="team_member_photo">photo 3</div>
            <div class="team_member_profile_text"><p>text</p></div>

            <div class="team_member_photo">photo 4</div>
            <div class="team_member_profile_text"><p>text</p></div>

            <div class="team_member_photo">photo 5</div>
            <div class="team_member_profile_text"><p>text</p></div>

  </div><!-- team_section -->
  </div><!-- team_wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
                                  #team_wrapper {
                       width: 990px;
                        height: 600px;
                    }

                    #team_section {
                        width: 100%;
                        background-color: #fee9f2;
                        height: 100%;
                        position: relative;
                        visibility: visible;
                    }

                    .team_member_photo {
                        background-color: #d3d9fe;
                        width: 150px;
                        height: 170px;
                        display: inline-block;
                        padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
                    }

                    .team_member_profile_text {
                        background-color: #fff;
                        height: 100%;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        position: relative;
                        float: left;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to tell jquery to close all the others.

Simply change your click-listener to this:

```
$("#team_section .team_member_photo").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().find('.team_member_profile_text').slideUp("fast");
    $this.next().slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work but is it possible to keep the close button, or add a new one?

Comment: yes, sure. The close-button should still work just like before: http://jsfiddle.net/2rFCz/2/